# scons: *** [out/linux/x86_64/release/resource/csdk/liboctbstack.so] Error 1 while installing and building iotivity

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scons, iotivity

## Scons error while installing and building iotivity on ubuntu 12.04

While trying to install iotivity on docker image ubuntu 12.04 i followed all instruction from iotivity Documentation for linux and when i use to run scons in root directory from iotivity i am getting following error in last and process failed

Following is my image and other information
Docker Image: Ubuntu:12.04
iotivity Documentation followed : documentation/linux/getting-started
Iotivity version used : iotivity-1.1.0.zip

Log file after running Scons is attached as .txt file

Any help is most welcomed and thanks in advance for that

[Docker-iotivity-error-log-file](https://drive.google.com/a/smartron.com/file/d/0B7YSpPbJGzENNGVKVHBhS3BscEE/view?usp=sharing)

i can't use more than 1 link so please forgive me for iotivity version and documentation full link.

Comment: Don't have permission to view log.

Comment: I updated permission, now you can view. sorry for trouble

Comment: [log-file-link-publically-shared](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7YSpPbJGzENNGVKVHBhS3BscEE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

It is due to missing file, cborparser_dup_string.c in tinycbor/Sconscript.

If you can add this file in extlibs/tinycbor/SConscript, it should resolve the issue.

```
cbor_src = [
    os.path.join(cborDir,'src/cborparser.c'),
    os.path.join(cborDir,'src/cborencoder.c'),
    os.path.join(cborDir,'src/cborerrorstrings.c'),
    os.path.join(cborDir,'src/cborparser_dup_stirng.c'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks to you, i solved it using degrade chbor to release v0.2. latest one is v0.3

Comment: If you solved it, post the solution and mark it the answer?